# Checking the database daily at a specific time and sending a notification

Tags: ios, database, notifications, uikit

I can't find the right solution for the following problem. There is a database SQLite with a list of names of employees and dates of birth. It is necessary every day at a certain time (for example, at 8:00) to check the database in the background and, if the employee has a birthday, send a notification with his name. I would be grateful for any advice.

```
// Checking the database before triggering a notification
func checkDataBase() -> (Bool, String) {
    var showNotification: Bool = false
    var employeeName: String = ""
    
    // Database checking
    
    return (showNotification, employeeName)
}
```

Comment: This is probably better done in a Remote Database with Push Notifications and/or pre-schedule this notification. Birthdays don't really change so just setup the notification ahead of time. For example add the notification when the employee is added or you can check periodically to make sure employee notifications are set maybe for the next couple of months, etc.

Comment: If your app is in the background, you can ask iOS to run a background task and check the database, but you cannot be sure of the time. Instead, I would recommend what Lorem Ipsum suggested, by setting up a remote push notification - this also takes some of the workload off of your app. See [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns) for more.